# How to pass in Content-Type and base64 value as a user in Taurus?

Tags: base64, yaml, performance-testing, content-type, taurus

I'm trying to assign a user value which is base64 characters and the Content-Type which is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". In my postman Content-Type is under Headers and user under body. Therefore i structured my yaml script like below :

```
execution:
  - concurrency: 10
    ramp-up: 20S
    hold-for: 1m
    scenario: sample

scenarios:
  sample:
    requests:
      - url: 'https://www.mtn.com/umbraco/surface/loginsurface/authenticate'
        method: POST
        headers:
          Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp, application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        Body:
          user: 'YWFkaWwuaaa2hhbkBzb3RpLdDpXZWxjb21lMTIzNA=='
```

However This isn't working when i'm running Taurus. Is the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [Taurus documentation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#YAML-JSON-Format-for-Config-Files)

   > As you know, JSON is a subset of YAML

   so Taurus supports both JSON and YAML configuration files
2. According to [JSON specification](https://jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-1-1-alt.html#service-procedure-and-parameter-names)

   > All names etc. are case-sensitive. Conforming implementations therefore MUST treat all names as being case-sensitive such the names "bar" and "BAR" would be seen as two distinct entities.
3. Looking further into [Taurus documentation on YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/#Lists-and-Dictionaries) format:

   > Dictionaries are collections of `key: value` mappings. All keys are case-sensitive.

   Therefore you just need to convert your `Body` to lowercase and everything should start working as expected (or at least result into following JMeter configuration)

   [image]

Full YAML just in case:

```
execution:
  - concurrency: 10
    ramp-up: 20S
    hold-for: 1m
    scenario: sample

scenarios:
  sample:
    requests:
      - url: 'https://www.mtn.com/umbraco/surface/loginsurface/authenticate'
        method: POST
        headers:
          Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp, application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        body:
          user: YWFkaWwuaaa2hhbkBzb3RpLdDpXZWxjb21lMTIzNA==
```

You can always [open JMeter GUI](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Open-JMeter-GUI) by running Taurus like:

```
bzt test.yaml -gui
```

or

```
bzt -o modules.jmeter.gui=true test.yaml
```

this way it will be easier to inspect the generated script.

More information:

- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)
- [Taurus JMeter Executor - HTTP Requests](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#HTTP-Requests)